# How change server and repositories setting after red hat was installed?

Tags: rhel, repository

During install Red Hat 6.5 x64 it asks about server type and repositories to select. Is it possible (and safe) to change these settings later via command console?

[image: Red hat option lists]

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called yum-utils, which you can install with:

```
yum install -y yum-utils
```

Once this is installed you can enable and disable repos with this command (assuming they're already installed):

```
yum-config-manager --enablerepo=repo_a
```

(where repo_a is the name of the repository you wish to enable.)

There is an important note about repositories however. When enabling and disabling repositories, I ALWAYS recommend you leave any third party repositories disabled by default, and only the RHEL default repositories enabled. This is due to dependency conflicts with some third party repositories that contain packages for bleeding edge editions (fedora, for example) that can cause some serious problems with core packages.

If you're having trouble installing them in the first place, then go to that particular repository's website and follow their instructions for Red Hat/CentOS. For example, [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat) are instructions for installing Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repo on CentOS/Red Hat.

---

As for your comment about safety, I'll give an example:

I usually disable all third party repositories with

```
yum-config-utils --disablereop=repo_a
```

leaving only the default repositories enabled. In your case, probably a repo called

> Enterprise Linux 6Server - some_sub_repository

Then, whenever i need to install a package from repo_a, i use this yum command

```
yum --enablerepo=repo_a install -y package_b
```

This has the advantage that if i were to update my installation with `yum update -y`, then updates are only pulled from the Red Hat repos, reducing the risk of destroying distribution specific packages.